# nls running through function multiple times per iteration?

Tags: r, nls

I'm new to R, and am running into a problem with nls that I don't understand. I've looked for documentation or answers about how the nls function in R works, but I can't find anything.

```
Test = data.frame(x = c(5, 10, 15, 25), y = c(5, 8, 12, 16))

fun = function(x, a, b) {
    cat("a =", a, ", b =", b, "\n")
    a*(x**b)
}

nls(y ~ fun(x, a, b), data = Test, start = list(a = 1.613, b = 0.718), trace = TRUE)
```

The output is the following:

```
a = 1.613 , b = 0.718 
a = 1.613 , b = 0.718 
a = 1.613 , b = 0.718 
a = 1.613 , b = 0.718 
0.7964401 :  1.613 0.718
a = 1.612723 , b = 0.7177708 
a = 1.612723 , b = 0.7177708 
a = 1.612723 , b = 0.7177708 
0.7960992 :  1.6127232 0.7177708
a = 1.612698 , b = 0.7177761 
a = 1.612698 , b = 0.7177761 
a = 1.612698 , b = 0.7177762 
0.7960992 :  1.6126980 0.7177761
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ fun(x, a, b)
   data: Test
     a      b 
1.6127 0.7178 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.7961

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.43e-06
```

It says it took two iterations to converge, but it looks like it ran through the function 10 times, and only changed the parameter values twice. Is there a reason for this? I couldn't find an explanation for how nls calculates the parameter guesses.

I'm trying to fit 600 data points to a large function, so this is taking up a lot of extra, unwanted time.

Comment: @alexisdebriere's answer is essentially correct. If you're able to specify a gradient function explicitly (search for "gradient" in `?nls`) you can avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that nls use the Gauss-Newton algorithm which does require a jacobian calculation, therefore you are seeing the numerical calculation of the jacobian values.

You can see that the calls are not exactly the same using the following code :

```
Test = data.frame(x = c(5, 10, 15, 25), y = c(5, 8, 12, 16))

fun = function(x, a, b) {
    cat("a =", sprintf("%0.10f",a), ", b =", sprintf("%0.10f",b), "\n")
    a*(x**b)
}

nls(y ~ fun(x, a, b), data = Test, start = list(a = 1.613, b = 0.718), trace = TRUE)
```

It just prints more decimal. The jacobian is estimated by doing minor perturbation on all the parameters.

```
a = 1.6130000000 , b = 0.7180000000 
a = 1.6130000000 , b = 0.7180000000 
a = 1.6130000240 , b = 0.7180000000 
a = 1.6130000000 , b = 0.7180000107 
0.7964401 :  1.613 0.718
a = 1.6127231539 , b = 0.7177708205 
a = 1.6127231779 , b = 0.7177708205 
a = 1.6127231539 , b = 0.7177708312 
0.7960992 :  1.6127232 0.7177708
a = 1.6126979985 , b = 0.7177761452 
a = 1.6126980225 , b = 0.7177761452 
a = 1.6126979985 , b = 0.7177761559 
0.7960992 :  1.6126980 0.7177761
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ fun(x, a, b)
   data: Test
     a      b 
1.6127 0.7178 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.7961

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.43e-06
```

So these calls are mandatory for nls to calculate the jacobian.